# MySQL ADD_DATE function from datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-update

I have a *dtinsert* column (with old values >> DATETIME type) ad *dtexpired* colum (without values >> DATE type). I want update dtexpired column from the value of dtins column.

This is the SQL query to try the statement. The update query not exist:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(dtinsert ,'%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 180 DAY)
FROM usertable
```

When execute, the statement, the value in dataset is without adding the 180 days.

How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `select` queries don't modify tables, period. you cannot change a table without an `update` query. all your select is doing is modifying the FETCHED value from the table. that modified value is not saved anywhere, and is destroyed when the query finishes executing/results are fetched.

Comment: I know what a good update. My select was an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `update` the table

```
UPDATE usertable 
SET dtexpired = DATE_ADD(dtinsert, INTERVAL 180 DAY)
```

You won't need the `DATE_FORMAT` since it converts a `datetime` into a string, thus forcing the `DATE_ADD` to parse it back.

Depending on the use cases, if you don't plan to update `dtinsert`s, you may want also to add a `WHERE dtexpired is NULL` to avoid useless updates.

Comment: Thanks, I was trust to use date_format. I try and work fine.